# Send Token Failing in Metamask

Tags: solidity, transactions, metamask, rinkeby, wrapped-tokens

I am trying to transfer 1 WETH betweeen my wallets.
It is not letting me
I have 2 WETH and I am transferring 1.
What could be the possible reason.

Network : Rinkeby

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enough ETH for paying the gas. You can't pay the gas with WETH. So, try to get some ETH.